Using Rational Root Theorem on big numbers for polynomials
One of the things I have tried finding answers to, but have always bothered me is about Rational Root Theorem when being applied to problems such as factoring of polynomials such as:
$k^3 + 6k^2 -1171k -3828 =0$
Naturally, with smaller constants, factoring wouldn't be so much of an issue. However in this case, this is rather cumbersome and time-consuming without computational tools.
Often times these kinds of questions appear on exams or olympiads and I have never found a way to avoid doing it aside from brute-force.

Really?  I can't imagine someone sadistic enough to put factoring $k^3 + 6 k^2 - 1171 k - 3828$ on an exam without allowing computational tools.

@RobertIsrael In general, this big no. But I did with somewhat smaller values such as in hundreds range which would leave me flabbergasted.
However I still don't get it if there's some sort of a trick or a method of approaching this kinds of problems. This question appeared in math olympiad, and brute forcing this by factoring this would leave a competitor out of time.
Also if you want to see sadistic questions for future reference, google "Jewish math questions USSR", however they were much more elegant and appeared trivial to beginners.

Could you give an example that actually did appear on an exam?

@RobertIsrael Unfortunately, no. This was half a decade ago, I can't really come up with a polynomial that actually has real solutions and also big last term as an example.
I noticed this question was part of math olympiads which usually last 2-4 hours. Considering it takes a lot of time to factor it, I thought that perhaps there is some more elegant approach to solving it rather than just brute factoring.

Using Cardano's formula can be quicker than trying out the rational root theorem for some cubics. Perhaps that's what they were going for...
